# Parsing string to entity with different fields names (key values)

Tags: .net, string, model, entity

I have a string message like this: `8=ABCD 5=DCBA 88=2 39=D`

And i have an entity:

```cs
public class Order : Entity {
   public string Account {get;set;}
   public char Type {get;set;}
   public string Status {get;set;}
   public string Something {get;set;}
}
```

And each attribute of the entity is equal to a number of the string pattern

```
8 = Account;
5 = Type;
88 = Status;
39 = Something;
```

I need to parse the string pattern to Order entity.

Anyone knows a solution to do this? without a loop or something like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing inbuilt; you'd have to parse it yourself; for example:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

static class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "8=ABCD 5=DCBA 88=2 39=D";
        var obj = new Order();
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, @"(?<=(\s|^))(?'key'[0-9]+)=(?'value'\S+)(?=($|\s))"))
        {
            var val = match.Groups["value"].Value;
            switch (match.Groups["key"].Value)
            {
                case "8":
                    obj.Account = val;
                    break;
                case "5":
                    obj.Type = val.FirstOrDefault(); // D from "DCBA" in the example
                    break;
                case "88":
                    obj.Status = val;
                    break;
                case "39":
                    obj.Something = val;
                    break;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Account); // ABCD
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Type); // D
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Status); // 2
        Console.WriteLine(obj.Something); // D
    }
}

public class Entity { }
public class Order : Entity
{
    public string Account { get; set; }
    public char Type { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }
}
```

As for "without a loop": you are fundamentally picking out multiple tokens here; you *could* try to write ways of doing this without a loop, but it doesn't seem a sensible goal, frankly.